# React failed to compile while trying to map an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The json response I'm getting back called `status` looks like this.

```
{map: "TheIsland", password: false, raw: {…}, maxplayers: 30, …}players:[{…}]"....
```

I'm trying to map the current names of the players property into individual JSX elements, but `.map` returns the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when applied to "props.status.players

I suspect this is because the component is loaded before `fetchStatus()` returns with `status`, so `.map` is running on an `undefined` property `players`. I added the `constructor`, but now React fails to compile because of a syntax error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchStatus } from "./../actions";

import "./arkStats.css";

class ArkStats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    players: []
  };
}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchStatus();
  }

  renderPlayers() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.status.players.map((players, index) =>
          <p key={index}>
            Hello, {players.name}!
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.status.name}
        {this.props.status.map}
        {this.renderPlayers()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ status }) {
  return { status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStatus })(ArkStats);
```

Thanks for the fix to my constructor! This has not changed the response I'm getting however, when ".map" is executed on "status.players". (Says it's still undefined.) Here is players as it appears when console logged in Chrome.

```
players: Array(3)
0:{name: "Jones", score: 0, time: 1573.2921142578125}
1:{name: "Matt", score: 0, time: 1348.6531982421875}
2:{name: "Skippy", score: 0, time: 285.5899963378906}
length:3
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, you don't use `this.setState` in the constructor, you just say `this.state = {...}`

Secondly, the reason is probably because like you said the 'players' value is undefined when the component first mounts. So simply add a check for this in the `renderPlayers()` function, i.e.

```
If 'players' value exists, return a map of it, else return null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `players` is not an array till your API call is finished, that is why you need to initialize the state on your react component for it to handle the first render.

Like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    players: []
  }
}
```

The syntax error is caused by this line `// {this.renderPlayers()}` [comments in JSX](http://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/) are like Javascript code block comments and they must be wrapped in curly braces ( `{ /* {this.renderPlayers() */ }`).

You also seem to have an extra curly brace:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.setState({players: []});
    } // this one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error because of you have extra curly brace '}' in you constructor and in your constructor you can't use setState instead initialize state.
So your constructor will be

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = { players: [] };
}
```

And syntax error caused because of extra } in constructor

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.setState({players: []});
    } // This one
  }
```

You can comment code inside JSX should changed from `// {this.renderPlayers()}` to `{/*this.renderPlayers()*/}`